# How can i use the component class variable in service class

Tags: angular, typescript

My service code is :

```
booking_type()
{
return this.http.get('https://booking.beglammed.com:3001/api/customer     /getAreaCategoryDetails');
}
services_detail()
{
return this.http.get('https://booking.beglammed.com:3001/api/customer/getAreaCategoryDetails');
}
```

and i subscribed it into component, component code is

```
ngOnInit() {
this.alldata.services_detail().subscribe( (response : Response  )=>
{
let data = response.json();
this.ServicesArea = data.data.servingAreas;
}
);
this.alldata.booking_type().subscribe( (response : Response  )=>
{
let data = response.json();
this.Bookings_detail = data.data.homeScreenData;
}
);
}
```

now i extract out booking_id and area_id by using **this.booking detail** and **this.SevicesArea**. Now i need to pass these **value area_id and booking_id** in next api which i want to call . then how can i use these values in service , because i am calling next api in service.``

Comment: I am assuming after you extract value you will call the other service from the component, if yes you can pass the value while you call the service. else pls share the code how you are calling the next service.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it simple in your component you do.

```
let data = response.json();
this.ServicesArea = data.data.servingAreas;
this.alldata.setServicesArea(this.ServicesArea);
}
);
this.alldata.booking_type().subscribe( (response : Response  )=>
{
let data = response.json();
this.Bookings_detail = data.data.homeScreenData;
this.alldata.setBookings_detail(this.Bookings_detail);
}
```

Then in your service you have two options use a getter ir call api call.
A api look like `this.http.get(https://booking.beglammed.com:3001/api/books/${this.getBookings_detail()}/${(this.getServicesArea()}` Make sure to use ` as quotes and not normal. Can't do it like normal cause stackoverflow mess up then cause use same quote to show code styling... [http Angular get example](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#get-hero-by-id)

Or with a mehod `getBooks(servicesArea: any, bookings_detail: any)`. If want same values in same async call put your second call inside the other call.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Observable forkJoin`

like this

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';

ngOnInit() {
  Observable.forkJoin([this.alldata.services_detail(), this.alldata.booking_type()]).mergeMap((data:any[]) => {
      this.ServicesArea = data[0].data.servingAreas;
      this.Bookings_detail = data[1].data.homeScreenData;

      //Here you can do whatever you want, bevor you request SomeData4
      return this.alldata.yournewmethod(this.ServicesArea, this.Bookings_detail); // pass the values to a new service method
  }).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data); // your data
  });
}
```